# Where would be a good place to ask advice on how to build a photo submission app?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am a developer. Say I wanted to create a service/site/app that involves people submitting snapshots? Where would I ask advice on this? Eg. what technology stack to use, existing solutions/APIs etc.?

What Stack Exchange site is appropriate for that? I think Stack Overflow will close my question as too broad.

Comment: I don't think there is one. You need to narrow things down yourself or pay someone to do the work for you.

Comment: chat.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You are welcome to examine, as a developer, how StackExchange performs image uploading (and hosting via imgur), though this aspect may be only a small detail of the site design project you have in mind.

Comment: maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ can be a place for you.

Comment: As @RobertLongson alludes to, Stack Exchange is *not* a substitute for paid consultations with people who know their business and can be paid to know yours.

Comment: I don't think that's fair. You can say that about anything...that forums aren't a substitute for paid consultants yet forums exist. Not just because they're free, but also because if you pay a consultant they often try to sell you something, regardless if it's what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you ask the question, [Software Recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) may be the site you are looking for. For an instance, there is a programming tag and an API tag.

Look at the [tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) and [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before you ask. There's still a chance your question(s) will be closed as too broad, so don't ask for multiple recommendations in one post